# structure for jquery in my mvc project

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, project-structure

whats the best way of structure jqueryfiles in my mvc app.
Now i have all my scripts in script folder and it starting to be difficult to have 
a good overview.

//thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used the following structure on my last project:

```
Scripts
|
|- jQuery
|- Libraries
|- Infrastructure
|- PageSpecific
```

jQuery contained jQuery and any plugins. Libraries contained other third-party libraries (e.g. underscore.js). Infrastructure contained shared JavaScript modules, e.g. one full of utility functions, or one for handling server-side account-management communications, etc. PageSpecific contained code to wire up event handlers and page-specific logic.

Answer (score 2):

The [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) has some minimal structure for JavaScript already. Anything I do will likely be built on top of that because there is at least a chance that another developer will have encountered it prior to hitting it in my project.

Boilerplate has a "js" subdirectory that contains all the JavaScript, another directory under that called "libs" that has just jQuery and Modernizr, and a "mylibs" directory where you're directed to put all the third party libraries (for example, the libraries for jQuery templates or Lawnchair).

```
js
  libs
  mylibs
  plugins.js
  script.js
```

They also recommend your short plugins should be concatenated in plugins.js and your basic script stuff go into script.js. Of course, that won't work for a large project, but you've at least got a start with just the js, js/libs, and js/mylibs structure. At the moment I'm using a JavaScript per HTML file with a corresponding name (blahblah.html + blahblah.js) but long term I know I'm going to need more structure than that.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your JavaScript files in the Scripts folder is the way to do it. If you want, you can use subfolders within the Scripts folder so that it's a little more organized.

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to keep your css files and javascripts organized within your web application.

- Have two main folders 'styles' and 'scripts' in the root folder of your application.
- Inside each of these folders, create sub folders that reflect specific module in your app like 'jquery', 'blueprint' etc and place those files over there.